# Ping 500 devices in Python and save their response informations on DB

Tags: python, concurrency, ping

My question may seem stupid, but i have a problem to solve: i need to ping 500 devices with python every X seconds, get the ping time, calculate the min/max/avg and save those values into a DB that will be continuously updated with newer ping data.

The db will have much rows as the pinged devices.

All in all, i have to do something that will be very similar to [SmokePing](https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/index.en.html), but in python.

To do so, i've started looking at [fping](https://github.com/NetworkEng/fping), and it seems the most logical way to do this, but i'm not sure about that.

Currently i'm looking for some advice in how i can solve this problem without stressing too much my CPU and the entire VM.

You guys, have some advices?

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow we do not give "some advice". Please ask a more specific question!

Answer (score 0):

Well, might seem a little bit stupid, but if you are working in windows you can use subprocess:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import random
from threading import Thread

    
adresses = ["list of ips"]
def ping(ip)
        systeminfo = subprocess.Popen("ping {}".format(ip),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
        out, err = systeminfo.communicate()
        with open("database.db", "w") as database:
             database.write(out)
             database.close()
# Start all threads. 
threads = []
for n in range(500):
    t = Thread(target=ping, args=([ip for ip in adresses],))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

# Wait all threads to finish.
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Try this code, im not 100% sure if works but is worth to try.